# Why does a glass tube show white bands after being heated with a torch?

Tags: heat, color, equipment

When I use a torch to split a glass tube, there's always a hazy white band which appears. Does anyone know what the cause of this is?

It was a hydrogen-oxygen torch. The glass is fused quartz glass, which should be pure silica.

[image: white band on glass tube apparent after being heated with a torch]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is sublimed silica according to the following reference at page 8.

http://www.public.asu.edu/~aomdw/GLASS/book.pdf